# How to determine Linksys router's IP when it is in gateway mode?

Tags: router, gateway

I have a Linksys WRK54G router that has previously been configured for Gateway mode, but I would like to access the web interface to the gateway but cannot determine its IP address.

How can I figure out the gateway's address?  The actual router is at 192.168.0.1 and I tried 192.168.1.1 for the gateway but that did not work.  The router lists the mac address for the gateway as being assigned 192.168.0.110 but that IP did not work either as I imagine that is its address from its WAN side, not its LAN side.

Diagram giving idea of network topology:

```
Printer  --> (wired to gateway)
Desktop1 --> (wired to gateway)
Laptop   --> (wireless to gateway)
  Wireless Linksys Gateway (Unknown IP) (Wired to router)--->
  Desktop2 (wired to router)-------------------------------->
                                         Main Router (192.168.0.1) --> DSL Modem
```

Comment: You actually don't explicitly say in your question, so: have you tried http://192.168.0.1/ ?

Comment: The 192.168.0.1 works fine to reach the router, but I want to reach the gateway.

Comment: But aren't the web interfaces for the "router" and the "gateway" combined? That is usually the case in my experience when they are run on a single box. Might be hidden under a different tab, but not more than that.

Comment: These are two different boxes.  The normal 192.168.0.1 gets the interface for the main router for the whole house down by the DSL modem.  I'm trying to access the wireless gateway on the desktop next to one of the computers plugged into the house wide router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the Linksys router is configured in Gateway mode or Router mode, it's web interface ought to be it's local IP address.

The gateway address is simply the address of the nearest router with the greatest connectivity. This is a separate and independent setting really.

What happens when you try to access http://192.168.0.1?

---

> Gateway Mode should be used if your Linksys router is hosting your
>   network's connection to the Internet.
>
> If the Linksys router is the main IP router to connect your network to
>   the Internet, then your Gateway IP is the same IP Address as the
>   Linksys router. If you have another router handling your network's
>   Internet connection, enter the IP Address of your main Internet router
>   here instead.

---

Update:

Your diagram doesn't make it clear whether your WRK54G is linked to the main router using the WRK54G's WAN port of one of it's LAN ports. In the former case it is routing IP, in the latter case it is switching Ethernet. In the former case, Desktop1's default gateway would have the IP-address of the WRK54G. In the latter case, it's configuration doesn't really matter.

It's probably sending some network traffic, so an `arp -a` on Desktop1 will reveal it's IP-address.

Worst case, (assuming the install CD-ROM is missing or can't be used to communicate with the WRK54G) use something like nmap or ping every IP-address in range.

Comment: 192.168.0.1 brings up the router behind the gateway, not the gateway.

Comment: @WilliamKF: what is the IP-address of your PC? What is the output of `ipconfig` in a cmd prompt window?

Comment: Currently it is 192.168.0.111, but that is provided by the underlying router, not the gateway.

Comment: Your network arrangement isn't clear to me (a diagram would help) Try using the setup CD-ROM to discover the WRK54G's IP-address.

Comment: I did not try 192.169.0.1 because that is not a valid reserved IP address for a LAN. (Should be 168, not 169, and the 168 address gets the router, not the gateway.) I have also added the diagram you requested.

Comment: @WilliamKF: the 169 was a typo, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 1):

1) reset the router 

or

2) disconnect all ethernet cables and use wireshark to see data packets coming from router after a power cycle (i'm assuming the router will send out packets here, otherwise this wont work)

Comment: Yes, I am considering just doing a factory reset, but was hoping to avoid that.  Have not tried wireshark yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, ping the broadcast address (should be 192.168.0.255) and see what replies.  You should get a reply from yourself, the router, and then everything else on the local subnet.  Assuming the WRK54G is listening at all (and it may not need to be if it is just bridging everything) then you will see a reply from it.  Point your browser at each IP you don't recognise and you'll find it.

You could use nmap scan or similar or you could script this, but that's probably more effort than is needed if you don't have a ton of devices on the subnet.

If it is in bridging mode then it might not have an IP address, at which point it's reset to defaults time if you want to reconfigure.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is your subnet address. You should change the address of one of your routers to be on the same subnet. If your pc is on subnet 192.168.0, then it cannot see 192.168.1
(as you probably have set the subnetmask to 255.255.255.0
/lars